# How can I create an Option type at runtime (reflection)?

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

Using reflection, I have determined the runtime type of a thing, t: Type.  Now I want to create a new Type of Option[t].  How can I do that?

```
val t: Type = ...
val optT: Type = ???  // Option of whatever t is
```

Why I want this:  I have a handler function that operates on a Type.  At compile time I have something like this:

```
trait Thing { name: String }
case class BigThing(name: String) extends Thing

case class Stuff[T <: Thing]( id: Int, maybeThing: Option[T] ) // contrived

def handler( t: Type ): Output = {...}
```

I can reflect that if I have a class of type Stuff, it has a member maybeThing of type Object[T] or even Object[Thing].  At runtime let's say I can determine that a specific object has T = BigThing, so I want to pass Option[BigThing], not Option[T] or Option[Thing] to handler().  That's why I'm trying to create a runtime type of Option[BigThing].

I did try the following but Scala didn't like it:

```
val newType = staticClass(s"Option[${runtimeTypeTAsString}]")
```

Comment: Where is `t` coming from?

Comment: So given `t: Type` representing a value of type `T`, you want a method `def makeOptionType(t: Type): Type` which returns the `Type` representing a value of type `Option[T]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [tutorial](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#instantiating-types)

> there are three ways to instantiate a `Type`.
>
> - via method `typeOf` on `scala.reflect.api.TypeTags`, which is mixed into Universe (simplest and most common).
> - Standard Types, such as `Int`, `Boolean`, `Any`, or `Unit` are accessible through the available universe.
> - Manual instantiation using factory methods such as `typeRef` or `polyType` on `scala.reflect.api.Types`, (not recommended).

Using the third way,

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class MyClass

val t: Type = typeOf[MyClass] //pckg.App.MyClass

val mirror = runtimeMirror(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader)

val optT: Type = mirror.universe.internal.typeRef(
  definitions.PredefModule.typeSignature, 
  definitions.OptionClass, 
  List(t)
) // Option[pckg.App.MyClass]

val optT1 : Type = typeOf[Option[MyClass]]

optT =:= optT1 // true
```